# Creating ObservableCollection within a constructor C#

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, constructor, observablecollection

I am relatively new to C# and encountered a problem.
I wanted to create a class named Folder, which has an ObservableCollection as a property.
The goal is to create instances of this class, to which I can add strings to the ObservableCollection.

Thank you in advance
Felix

```
class FolderClass
{
    public static ObservableCollection<VocabClass> VocabList { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FolderClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        VocabList = new ObservableCollection<VocabClass> { };
    }

}


public class VocabClass
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    public VocabClass(string word, string translation)
    {
        Word = word;
        Translation = translation;
    }
}


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
         FolderClass Firstobject = new FolderClass("firstObject");
         string name = Firstobject.Name; //accessable
         var Word = Firstobject.Vocablist; //cannot be accessed
    }

 }
```

Comment: `VocabList` should not be static.

Comment: You can’t access VocabList from an instance of FolderClass because it’s static- make it non static or do FolderClass. VocabList

Comment: Thank you so far, that already solved the problem, but I have another question. I set up a Binding to the "Word" property of the VocabClass. This property is also not accessible. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that? Thank you

Comment: @auburg you can actually access it, it's the other way around that isn't allowed. @FelixB For the solution it's important to know if each instance should have it's own list (remove the `static` keyword) or you want a single shared list (remove the creation inside the constructor and change the declaration to `public static ObservableCollection<VocabClass> = new ObservableCollection<VocabClass>();`. That said be carefull with `static` fields and classes, they can be hard to maintain

Comment: You need to provide more context.  I'd suggest you post a new question with the details of the problem.  Please read [ask] for guidance in posting a good question

Comment: I managed to fix the problem I had. I just have to be more aware when to use the static attribute. Thank you for your support!